# How do i make that anything else that the user inputs will get an error message except my commands

Tags: python-3.x

I made a code that shows a list of commands when you type cmds and a list of names (the program is for showing information about that name).I alredy made the program repeatedly ask for input without break.Now i want my code to display and error message when the user inputs something thats not in cmds list.Currently all the commands in my code that provide and output are cmds, Names and some names.

```
#This is only a piece of code for the command cmds in my program
print("Enter a name for information")
print("Type cmds for a list of commands")
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == "cmds":
        print("Names - displays a list of all names that have information")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if inp not in list_of_commands:
    print("Not a recognized command")
```

Or, if you are testing for each legal command individually (to respond to them), once you've tried all the legal ones w/o success, you know you have an illegal one.

Comment: i tried using that code and it didnt work. i put that list_of_commands = cmds also didnt work (im new to coding) also tried changing list_of_commands to cmds or Names and still doesnt work. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Did you define `list_of_commands` to be a list of your commands (as the name suggests)?